# How to centre navbar logo in Boostrap 4 with nav-links below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I can't seem to get the navbar logo to centre align with the nav-links centre below it. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I've checked out a few other posts regarding this issue but all seem to be using older versions of bootstrap. I am currently using bootstrap 4.0.

Specifically, I want the logo on its own separate row, not on the same one as the links.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/h-tech-logo-cropped.png"/></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Like [this](https://prnt.sc/ixzizi) ?

Comment: Yes, like that. My question has been marked as duplicate, but it is not as I want the logo to be on its own row like you have demonstrated.

Comment: @ZimSystem this question is *not* a duplicate. It wants something completely different doing than suggested in said duplicate.

Comment: [This question *is* being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365291/is-this-question-actually-a-duplicate)

Comment: I have re-opened, but I think the means will be as same as the other question. It also looks as if there wasn't any effort to center the links or put content on separate rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of using the **flexbox** and **auto-margin** utils as explained in the many other "Bootstrap 4 Navbar Center" questions...

- The navbar is `display:flex` so use `flex-column` to make content stack
- Use `mx-auto` for auto x-axis margins to center.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light flex-column">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"><img src="img/h-tech-logo-cropped.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Responsive demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/KpAE8eMJGS)

---

Related **"Bootstrap 4 Navbar Center"** questions:
[Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447)
[Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126)
[Center an element in Bootstrap 4 Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867603)
[How to center nav-items in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738067)

Comment: Yes it does, thats fantastic thank-you. I think I may be struggling to use the correct search terms. I'm fairly new to stack overflow so I will definitely work on getting better at checking for existing posts.